# How to redirect a REST query to a non-REST view only when a query parameter is set?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a REST viewset for which I want to be able to perform a redirection to a non-REST view if a request comes in with a specific flag. I want:

1. A `GET` to my viewset to redirect to another view when `flag` is set on the request and return a JSON response otherwise.
2. If the client sets the `Accept` HTTP so both JSON or HTML are possible, I want the format returned to be JSON if `flag` is not set, and HTML when `flag` is set. (That is, the default format should vary depending on whether `flag` is set.)
3. The only valid response format is HTML when flag is set, and JSON when flag is unset.

This is what I have:

```
class FooViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                 viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer, )

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # The original code validates the value of `flag` but
        # that's not relevant to the issue here.
        flag = request.GET.get('flag', None)

        if flag:
            if request.accepted_renderer.media_type != "text/html":
                raise NotAcceptable

            return HttpResponseRedirect(SomeModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs["pk"])
                                        .get_absolute_url())

        if request.accepted_renderer.media_type != "application/json":
            raise NotAcceptable

        return super(FooViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem with the code above is that the accepted renderer never has the `media_type` set to `text/html` since I don't have a renderer that accepts `text/html`. I don't want to add an HTML `renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer` to `renderer_classes` because I don't actually want to use that renderer but return a `HttpResponseRedirect` directly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make HTML a Possible Format

You need to set things up so that DRF's `APIView` (by way of `viewsets.GenericViewSet`), which implements the content negotiation, allows requests that require HTML. The easiest way to do this is to just add a renderer that produces HTML to `renderer_classes`. If you return an `HttpResponse` or something derived from `HttpResponse`, **Django REST Framework will just bypass the renderer.** So you're using it only to allow requests that want an HTML response, but not for actually rendering anything.

#### Validate Formats Depending on `flag`

**`flag` unset**

If you add the HTML renderer **after** `renderers.JSONRenderer` then your code will handle the case where `flag` is unset properly. If both JSON and HTML are possible, JSON will win because the renderer for it is earlier in the list. So if `request.accepted_renderer.media_type != "application/json"` that's only because the client did not allow for a JSON response.

**`flag` set**

You need to add a bit of logic to your handling case where `flag` is set so that you reject the request unless HTML is a possible response format. Remember as explained above that if the client allows both JSON and HTML, and the JSON renderer is first in the list of renderers, JSON will be preferred by default. So you have to check manually whether HTML was *allowed* by the query. Here's an example. The crucial code is in the `html_possible` method:

```
class FooViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                 viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer, renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        flag = request.GET.get('flag', None)

        if flag:
            if not self.html_possible(request):
                raise NotAcceptable

            return HttpResponseRedirect(SomeModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs["pk"])
                                        .get_absolute_url())

        if request.accepted_renderer.media_type != "application/json":
            raise NotAcceptable

        return super(FooViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def html_possible(self, request):
        from rest_framework.utils.mediatypes import media_type_matches

        conneg = self.get_content_negotiator()
        accepts = conneg.get_accept_list(request)
        return any(media_type_matches(accept,
                                      renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer.media_type)
                   for accept in accepts)
```

What `html_possible` does is get a content negotiator instance, use it to get the list of media types accepted, and determine whether any of them allows us to return HTML. If yes, then we're good to go.

You could conceivably avoid creating an instance of the negotiator and just implement `conneg.get_accept_list` yourself. It is pretty simple code but I prefer to depend on DRF's code in case there are some future changes to that logic.